# Geometry Nodes for Manipulating the shape of animal scales

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am currently working on a way to cover a model with scales in a modular way. Therefore I’m using a triangulated mesh, where every vertex gets replaced by a Scale. So far, everything works quite nicely, but to take it to the next level, I need a way to deform the scales according to the average angle the edges are connecting with it, and secondly a way to scale the scales according to the average length of these edges. Unfortunately, I can’t figure out a way to access the needed data (the edges connected to the vertex) but I thought the should be a way to do so.
[image: progress so far]

I hope there is someone able to help me :)
Thanks in advance

Nico

Answer (score 1):

From what I know there isn't an attribute that can let you do that.
The solution I would suggest is a script that finds the average length of a vertex's edges and stores that to a custom attribute that you can access with geometry nodes.
The angle thing would be more difficult to achieve depending on what exactly you mean by the average angle, but I can imagine some ways it could be done with vectors and this method.

Comment: Don't the attributes get recalculated all the time, and thus would get cleaned up when I change anything about the object? Sry if these questions are dumb, I'm not that deep into scripting in blender yet :D Also: kinda sad that this seems not to be possible without scripting. I mean isn't it quite the thing about geometry nodes, that u don't need to write real code?

Comment: @nico.lindenlauf geometry nodes are still quite new, so there's a lot of features that haven't been implemented yet. In 3.0 they get a new redesign! But still no way to access neighboring vertices afaik :/ maybe one day...